# How do I avoid labels overflowing container boundaries with PlantUML?

Tags: plantuml

I'm trying to find a way to make sure labels of items in a container do not overflow or overlap container boundaries. So far I could not find any setting that would help. 
This content:

```
@startuml
left to right direction

node "inner" {
    ()XyzAdapter
}

node "inner-impl" {
    [XTXAdapter] - XyzAdapter
}

node "Other Groups" {
  FTP - [Second Component]
  [First Component] --> FTP
}

@enduml
```

Creates the following rendering in every online/offline PlantUML setup I could get my hands on:

[image]

As you can see, both FTP and XyzAdapter are rendered without any concern for their container boundaries.
It is even worse from within Vs. Code using the PlantUML plugin because it also decreases the space between containers.

Are there any parameters or tricks I can use to avoid this? You can use both [liveuml](https://liveuml.com/) and [planttext](https://www.planttext.com/) to observe this behaviour.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not insist on keeping the exact same layout, you could add another dash ("-") where you have only used one in order to have two dashes for all your edges. That renders  a diagram like the one below with all labels being legible.

```
@startuml
left to right direction

node "inner" {
    ()XyzAdapter
}

node "inner-impl" {
    [XTXAdapter] -- XyzAdapter
}

node "Other Groups" {
  FTP -- [Second Component]
  [First Component] --> FTP
}

@enduml
```

[image]

Comment: I had no idea more dashes led to more distance! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Double dashes are the standard and respect the defined direction (left to right in the example). Use a single dash to force - in this case - vertical instead of horizontal lines.